# Unexpected Java performance

Tags: java, performance

I have just thrown everything I know about Java optimisation out the window.  I have the following task:

Given a 2D array representing a playing field and a position on the field, fill another array with the number of steps a player can make to get to every other position in the field.  The player can move up, down, left and right.  For example, the first neighbours will be all 1's, with the diagonals being all 2's.

For the first attempt, I tried a simple 4-way floodfill algorithm.  It wad dreadfully slow.

Secondly, I decided to get rid of the recursion and use a simple Queue.  It worked lovely and gave a huge speed-up (very roughly 20x). Here is the code:

```
private void fillCounterArray(int[] counters, int position) {
    Queue<Integer> queue = new ArrayDeque<Integer>(900);

    // Obtain the possible destinations from position, check the valid ones
    // and add it the stack.
    int[] destination = board.getPossibleDestinations(position);
    for (int i = 0; i < destination.length; i++) {
        if (board.getBoard()[destination[i]] == Board.CLEAR) {
            counters[destination[i]] = 1;
            queue.add(destination[i]);
        }
    }

    // Now fill up the space.
    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        int pos = queue.remove();
        int steps = counters[pos];            
        destination = board.getPossibleDestinations(pos);
        for (int i = 0; i < destination.length; i++) {
            int dest = destination[i];
            if (board.getBoard()[dest] == Board.CLEAR && (counters[dest] > steps + 1 || counters[dest] == 0)) {
                counters[dest] = steps + 1;
                queue.add(dest);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, "common-sense" told me that the queue operations with a static array and an int-pointer would be faster. So I removed the Queue and use a standard int[] array.  The code is identical, except for the queue-like operations.  It now looks like this (As you can see, I use to live by the C-side :)):

```
private void fillCounterArray(int[] counters, int position) {

    // Array and its pointer.
    int[] queue = new int[900]; // max size of field
    int head = 0;

    // Obtain the possible destinations from position, check the valid ones
    // and add it the stack.
    int[] destination = board.getPossibleDestinations(position);
    for (int i = 0; i < destination.length; i++) {
        if (board.getBoard()[destination[i]] == Board.CLEAR) {
            counters[destination[i]] = 1;
            queue[head++] = dest[i];
        }
    }

    // Now fill up the space.
    while (head > 0) {
        int pos = queue[--head];
        int steps = counters[pos];

        destination = board.getPossibleDestinations(pos);
        for (int i = 0; i < destination.length; i++) {
            int dest = destination[i];
            if (board.getBoard()[dest] == Board.CLEAR && (counters[dest] > steps + 1 || counters[dest] == 0)) {
                counters[dest] = steps + 1;
                queue[head++] = dest;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I ran this "optimised code" it was significantly slower than using the Queue and only about twice as fast as the recursive technique. There is also hardly any difference when I declare the array as an instance variable. How is this possible?

Comment: Can you add `getPossibleDestinations` (and `getBoard()`) method implementation

Comment: There's no need... it's a simple array lookup and constant in both implementations.  All it does is give the four neighbours for a given position.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java to eliminate benchmarking caveats.

Comment: Vadzim, I am not trying to benchmark the above.  When I run each version, the difference in performance is blatantly obvious.  The one is about 10 times faster than the other and it is completely counter-intuitive. If I apply correct benchmarking techniques, all I'll end up with is more accurate estimate of the performance difference.

Comment: Be aware that `Queue.offer()` can return false if the element is not added and that could explain the difference (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html#offer(E))

Comment: @RC - I've changed offer to add and get basically the same performance.  It makes sense though, as the test cases for the algorithm pass in both instances.

Comment: You sure you're getting through a warm-up phase? Most JVMs start out interpreting code. Could be that using the queue somehow triggers a  compile to native sooner.

Comment: @Tony... thought occurred to me to.  I continue to run the program for several minutes (it gets called periodically), yet... it still gives poor performance.  It does not make sense, a simple array should be faster, should it not??

Comment: @Jaco Van Niekerk, the point about benchmarking caveats is that you may be measuring totally different things. Like interpreted code with JIT-compiled, that would easily give 20x difference.

Comment: probably because java array bound checking?

Comment: @Vadzim, does this imply that the ArrayDeque I am using may be natively/JIT copiled, while the array implementation is not?  How can one ascertain that?

Comment: @Jaco Van Niekerk, by running the same test in a loop multiple (thousands) times. See the link above.

Comment: @Vlad, I am doing just that... that method is called 1000's of times as part of a alpha-beta search.  Only the queue implementation changes... benchmarking is not the issue, really.  If I ONLY change the implementation as above, I get a huge and very noticeable performance difference.  I just cannot understand how a direct int-array implementation can be so much slower than a ArrayDeque.

Comment: How much filled your board is when you call this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reversed the order while optimising I think;

```
The queue is fifo, first in first out
The array is lifo, last in first out, as you walk it downwards
```

That will usually give you different performance ;-)

Comment: Absolutely spot-on.  How could I have missed that... After changing to a head and tail pointer, the code outperforms the Dequeue as expected. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Insert two Counters in each Loop one in the for loop and one in the while loop in both versions, compare the numbers you get at the end, how many rounds do you make in each version, if you have another Loop in `getPossibleDestination` then log the `pos` variable too. 
I guess that would be a good starting point to figure it out.

Another way would be to print the time difference on different lines in your program, let say before the 1st loop, between both and at the end, once you compare results and know where it takes a long time in the second Version you can print timestamps in the loop on different lines.

Comment: I'm not sure what that would accomplish.  The counters will be the same. It is only the queue operations that have changed from a standard Queue to an int-array.  The "logic" is the same.

Comment: I didnt read the whole code, i would log it anyway, it doesnt really coat that much , but its up to you, try the timelog if your sure about the number of rounds

Comment: Seeing the code i notices queue.offer(destination[i]); this returns a boolean value according to success or failure, consider this is failing to insert this will effect the rounds in your second loop (Theoretically)

Comment: I changed offer() to add(), test cases still pass, same results, same performance.

Comment: with the typing effort for all the comments you could have easly benchmarked it and found the problems.

Comment: I disagree with you... I already know the code is equivalent (no counters needed) and I already know EXACTLY where, namely where the ArrayDeque is substituted with an int-array (no timing needed). Thanks anwyay...

Comment: The code is not entirely equivalent. As far as I can see you use Deque in a FIFO fashion, while your int[] is used as a stack (LIFO). So this might make a difference in how many rounds are needed.

Comment: @OD, apologies, your counter method would have pointed out the above.  Sorry, should have listed to you.